# Find all positive rational solutions to $x^y = y^x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Note:
This is essentially the same as
[What are the positive rational solutions of $x^{(x+y)} = (x+y)^y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474424/what-are-the-positive-rational-solutions-of-xxy-xyy),
but that did not have any good answers.

In my answer to [Understanding the graph for $x^y = y^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785784/understanding-the-graph-for-xy-yx/785818#785818),
I showed that
a parameterization of
$x^y = y^x$
is
$x = r^{1/(r-1)}$
and
$y = r^{r/(r-1)}$.
Setting
$r = 1+1/n$,
where $n$ is a positive integer,
gives
$x = (1+1/n)^n$
and
$y = (1+1/n)^{n+1}$
as rational solutions.

For $n=1$, $x=2$ and $y=4$, which is well known.

For $n=2$, $x=9/4$ and $y=27/8$, which is not well known.

To check the $n=2$ case,
$(9/4)^{27/8}
=((3/2)^2)^{27/8}
=(3/2)^{54/8}
=(3/2)^{27/4}
$
and
$(27/8)^{9/4}
=((3/2)^3)^{9/4}
=(3/2)^{27/4}
$.

I believe that these are *all* the
positive rational solutions,
but I do not have a proof.

Comment: you also have $x = y = $anything. I don't think these are included in the ones you gave?

Comment: If any rational number can be written in the form $1+1/n$, then yes. This is not true, and hence, the conclusion is false.

Comment: The only rational solutions are $(\pm 2, \pm 4)$. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205260/solutions-of-diophantine-equations-xy-yx) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y).

Comment: Not true. I added the example $x = 9/4$ and $y = 27/8$.

Comment: [Aryabhata's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9515/11619) gives links to a proof of the fact that for $(x,y)$ to be rational it is, indeed, sufficient and necessary that $r=1+1/n$, $n$ integer. The integer $n$ does not have to be positive. For example $n=-2$ gives $x=4$, $y=2$ (you get the swapped solutions that way).