# Find all positive rational numbers such that $n^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ is rational too

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I was trying to find all rational numbers $n$ such that $n^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ is rational too.
I found this question a little bit tricky and doesn't know how to beginn. I would really appreciate a little help. Thank you very much !

Comment: It seems to be related to the rational parametrizations for the equation $x^y=y^x$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785836/find-all-positive-rational-solutions-to-xy-yx?noredirect=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y/9515#9515). So the parametric equations are
$x=t^{\frac1{t-1}}$,  $y=t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this isn't a duplicate, strictly speaking, since the OP does not require $x$ to be positive, and the question does make sense for some negative rationals as well.

Comment: @Mastrem The title says "Find all *positive* rational numbers." But one can extend this, if necessary (it looks like the standard contest question is for positive  rational numbers).

Comment: Ah, sure. I'll delete my answer, since it dealt mostly with the positive case anyway